# Why does Time::HiRes::stat break list subscripting?

Tags: arrays, perl, time-hires

I can't figure out what's going on here. Where does the 8 below come from?

[`Time::HiRes`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::HiRes) provides an overload of `stat` which expands the times to have high-resolution (which is supported on my system).

```
$ perl  -MTime::HiRes -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[8], "\n"'              # V1
1322915623
$ perl  -MTime::HiRes=stat -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[8], "\n"'         # V2
8
$ perl  -MTime::HiRes=stat -e '@a = stat("foo"); print $a[8], "\n"'   # V3
1322915623
```

That particular file doesn't have a high-resolution timestamp, but that's not the mystery: the mystery is V2, which prints 8. In fact, it always prints the number in square brackets.

The obvious answer, it parses differently, does not seem correct:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -MTime::HiRes -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[8], "\n"'         # V1
use Time::HiRes;
print((stat 'foo')[8], "\n");
-e syntax OK
$ perl -MO=Deparse -MTime::HiRes=stat -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[8], "\n"'    # V2
use Time::HiRes (split(/,/, 'stat', 0));
print((stat 'foo')[8], "\n");
-e syntax OK
```

They deparse the same (other than the different option to `use Time::HiRes`).

It works fine if I use my own function in similar syntax, and I can't get the "wrong" answer even if I return something silly from my function:

```
$ perl -e 'sub bar() { return qw(a b c d e f g h i j) }; print +(bar)[8], "\n"'
i
$ perl -e 'sub bar() { return undef }; print +(bar)[8], "\n"'

$
```

This is Debian's perl package, version 5.14.2-5. I get the same results with 5.10.1-17squeeze2.

**How does V2, above, produce 8?** Am I misunderstanding Perl syntax in some way, or do I just need to file a bug report?

edit: As @cjm says, this is a bug. It has been fixed in Time-HiRes-1.9725 according to the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a bug, although I'm not sure whether it's in core Perl or in Time::HiRes.  I get the same results with Perl 5.14.2 on Gentoo (and also with 5.8.9 and 5.10.0).  Have you noticed that it doesn't matter what you put in the subscript?

```
$ perl -MTime::HiRes=stat -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[215.4], "\n"' 
215.4
$ perl -MTime::HiRes=stat -e 'print +(stat("foo"))["bar"], "\n"'
bar
```

I'd probably [report it in Time::HiRes](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Time-HiRes) first.

Note:  While they deparse the same, they do generate different opcodes (due to the difference between calling a built-in and a user-defined sub):

```
$ perl -MO=Concise -MTime::HiRes -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[8], "\n"' 
c  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 271 -e:1) v:{ ->3
b     <@> print vK ->c
3        <0> pushmark s ->4
9        <2> lslice lK/2 ->a
-           <1> ex-list lK ->6
4              <0> pushmark s ->5
5              <$> const(IV 8) s ->6
-           <1> ex-list lK ->9
6              <0> pushmark s ->7
8              <1> stat lK/1 ->9
7                 <$> const(PV "foo") s ->8
a        <$> const(PV "\n") s ->b
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise -MTime::HiRes=stat -e 'print +(stat("foo"))[8], "\n"' 
e  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 271 -e:1) v:{ ->3
d     <@> print vK ->e
3        <0> pushmark s ->4
b        <2> lslice lK/2 ->c
-           <1> ex-list lK ->6
4              <0> pushmark s ->5
5              <$> const(IV 8) s ->6
-           <1> ex-list lK ->b
6              <0> pushmark s ->7
a              <1> entersub[t1] lKS/TARG,1 ->b
-                 <1> ex-list lK ->a
7                    <0> pushmark s ->8
8                    <$> const(PV "foo") sM ->9
-                    <1> ex-rv2cv sK ->-
9                       <$> gv(*stat) s ->a
c        <$> const(PV "\n") s ->d
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Thank you, bug reported https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72926 ... you may want to add your `$Time::HiRes::VERSION`s, I don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the command line execution so I speak to oddities in its workings.

I have seen unexpected results when using a subscript on a function that should return an array.

```
$y = localtime()[5];    # failed for me (I forget just how)
```

but

```
$y = (localtime())[5];  # worked fine
```

This suggests to me a bug in (my implementation of) Perl.  A better test might be to try it in an actual script:

```
use Time::HiRes qw(stat);

my @x = stat("foo");

print $x[8],"\n";
```

I am using ActiveState's Perl on WinXP so my results may not be the same.  Still, I think it may be useful to try it in very simple code to see what it does.

Comment: This is not a bug: Perl's [list indexing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) syntax is `(LIST)[INDEX]`. The parentheses are required.  (The behavior observed by derobert and cjm, however, _is_ a bug.)